# Podcasts useful for improving writing skills

Tags: resources

Any podcasts that can help with writing skills?

(One per answer please, I'll add my own fave to get started.)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

My favourite is **[Writing Excuses](http://www.writingexcuses.com/)**

"15 minutes long because you're in a hurry, and we're not that smart!"

Focus is on fiction (especially spec fiction) and advice for aspiring writers. The hosts are:

- Brandon Sanderson (*Wheel of Time, Mistborn,* etc)
- Howard Taylor (*Schlock Mercenary*)
- Dan Wells (*I Am Not a Serial Killer, etc*)
- Mary Robinette Kowal (*Shades of Milk and Honey, etc*)

And they have guest stars and stuff.

More about it on [my blog](http://mgowen.com/2010/11/12/writing-excuses/).

Comment: Fantastic podcast. Very informative, but also short enough to digest easily.

Comment: if nothing else, one of the best taglines for a podcast.  Ever.

Answer (score 7):

I would like to add [I Should be Writing](http://isbw.murlafferty.com/) my Mur Lafferty. It was the first writing blog I ever listen to and I've gotten quiet a bit of good advice from Mur over the years.

Mur has also done a number of interviews with different professionals, including people like Neil Gaiman. It's worth your time to check it out.

Comment: I enjoyed the episode I tried of this one, though I don't listen regularly because it went on a bit long and didn't seem very structured (seemed like about 20 mins of content stretched out to an hour).

Comment: "60 minutes long because you're not writing anyway, and we're too smart for our own good!"

Comment: @erikric  I just *love* that comment

Answer (score 3):

If you're interested in writing speculative fiction, I highly recommend the [Odyssey Podcasts](http://www.sff.net/odyssey/podcasts.html), which are recorded sessions from the annual Odyssey Writing Workshop.

Comment: This is good...