# Are there any good magazines about writing?

Tags: technique, magazines, inspiration

As in all other fields I'm interested in, I love to have a subscribtion that makes sure some hugely inspirational material gets dropped into my mailbox once in a while. I'm not looking for magazines that prints stories submitted by users, but rather one that focuses on the process of writing and writing technique.

Are there any such out there, or is online the only place to be in these matters?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is always the classic, [Writers Digest](http://www.writersdigest.com/).

Comment: Is that a real thing!? I remember it just for its infamous condensed books!

Comment: @Lorenzo that sounds more like Readers Digest then Writers Digest.

Comment: Oh! I thought it was the same thing!

Answer (score 4):

Writers Digest is a fine magazine; another to consider is "the writer" - http://www.writermag.com/

I would also recommend magazines that include writing you consider "good" that can be inspiring; Inc. Magazine (http://www.inc.com/ ) comes to mind.   You can generally get a subscription for Inc. for $10/USD per year if you shop around, and most of the website is free.

Another place to look is /podcasts/ - the "Writing Excuses" podcast is a 15-minute free weekly audio-show treasure trove - http://www.writingexcuses.com/

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

If you know German:

http://www.textartmagazin.de/

Answer (score 1):

I personally usually collect different articles that I find on the web about writing techniques etc. and create a [page turning pdf](http://tuxbrain.com/page-turning-pdf/page-turning-effect-in-pdf)for myself, but if you prefer an actual magazine I really liked [The Writer](https://www.writermag.com/). Also just looked it up and found [this post](http://www.blurb.com/blog/our-favorite-magazines-for-writers/)about different magazines for writers including a description - might also be something you want to check out.

Answer (score 0):

Poets & Writers Magazine is published in print six times a year.

http://www.pw.org/magazine

The magazine focuses more on writing process and publishing process than on point-by-point writing technique, but its articles explore many angles of writing and the writing life.

Typical topics include: inspiration; creativity; writer's block; effective writing habits; interviews with authors; Q&As with editors and agents; social media strategies; small presses; ebooks; self-publishing; crowdfunding; grants and awards; and more.

Their website has many features, including additional online-only articles and resources such as searchable databases for contests, residencies and conferences.  They also started a digital format of the magazine in 2010 (though I can't speak personally to that; I subscribe to the print version).