# Please suggest an exemplary book for professional writing

Tags: book-rec

I would like to improve my writing style, grammar, and vocabulary, but I'm having a hard time finding a good exemplary book. Most of books I find perfect at first, turn out to be full of flaws and/or informal expressions.

I'm looking for a non-fiction English book that is written in formal -but not obsolete- style. An advanced level book with impeccable vocabulary, grammar, and structures that I can safely follow in my essays (for instance, in the GRE analytical writing essays).

In other words, I'm looking for a "holy book" for professional writers. Please let me know if you know one.

Comment: Possibly a partial duplicate of this: [What are good reads about writing?](http://writers.stackexchange.com/q/148/26)

Comment: Hmm, I missed this on its first go-around. Any objections if I merge it into http://writers.stackexchange.com/q/148/ ? I should hope any exemplary books would also be counted as "good."

Comment: Ok, I've merged them.