# Books on character development

Tags: resources, character-development

Are there any good books to learn about character development for mystery/thriller genre fiction? For example, when to introduce the character(s), how much background info to give about each character, how to make the character evolve through the struggles etc etc.

Comment: Related: [What are good reads about writing?](http://writers.stackexchange.com/q/148/26)

Comment: This might be a list question... thoughts, people?

Comment: Agreed; this is one of many questions asking for books about writing. List questions are okay if there are only a few possible answers, which may be the case here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would suggest:

1. [Creating Unforgettable Characters](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0805011714) by Linda Seger. This is actually listed as recommended reading for applicants to ABC network's writing fellowship.
2. [45 Master Characters](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1599635348) and [A Writer's Guide to Characterization](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1599635577) by Victoria Schmidt. Reviews for these can come off mixed, but I like how Schmidt uses the hero's journey and mythological character archetypes as templates.
3. Last, but not least, there's [Dynamic Characters](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1582973199) by Nancy Kress. I would dive into this for when you really want to push that envelope.
4. If you'd like a good primer on thrillers or mysteries, read [How to Write a Damn Good Thriller](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0312575076) and [How to Write a Damn Good Mystery](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0312304463) by James N. Frey. I found his books helpful, but opinions on his work are pretty polarizing. You can play it safe by borrowing these from your library. For something more modern, check out Jodie Renner's [How to Write a Killer Thriller](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1490389946).
5. For further inspiration, I would also read major works by Raymond Chandler ("Farewell, My Lovely), Dashiell Hammett ("The Maltese Falcon"), and John Le Carre ("Tinker, Tailor, Soldier, Spy").

Answer (score 2):

It is not about characters in mystery/thrillers specifically, but Orson Scott Cards [Characters & Viewpoint](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/9441466-characters-viewpoint) is considered by many (myself included) to be one of the best books on the subject.

For a more general description of character develpoment in a plot i highly recommend Larry Brooks' [Story Engineering](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/9912752-story-engineering)

Answer (score 2):

Two of the best Character-building books for me are:

1. [Write Great Fiction - Characters, Emotion & Viewpoint, by Nancy Kress - amazon link](http://amzn.to/2p9mss3)

   You can read this book for free on Amazon if you are a Kindle Unlimited (Kindle Online Library) member.
   Its a very readable book and explains character creation very well.

and

2. [Creating Characters: The Complete Guide to Populating Your Fiction - amazon link](http://amzn.to/2pIhHZB), (compilation) by various authors